# Haskell Higher Order Function

Tags: database, haskell

I'm having trouble outputting certain bits of information from this given database:

```
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2011, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
    ("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
        ("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2006, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"])]
```

Note: this is only part of the database due to the size of the list.

I'm trying to write a function which allows the user to input a year and output ONLY the film titles..I have done a similar one with fans to which the user enters a Fan name and outputs the film they are a fan of...The code to this is shown below:

```
filmsByFan y = map (\(a,_,_,_) -> a) $ filter (\(_,_,_,a) -> elem y a) testDatabase
```

This works 100%, and so I tried a similar one with byYear:

```
filmsByYear y = map (\(a,_,_,_) -> a) $ filter (\(_,_,a,_) -> elem y a) testDatabase
```

But this does not compile...Is this because the type Year is set as an Int? If so is there a solution to my problem in a similar way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you want to check whether person `y` is *contained* in the list of fans, hence `elem y a`.

In the second case, you want to check whether year `y` is *equal* to the year of the film, so you would simply check for equality, `a == y`:

```
filmsByYear y = map (\(a,_,_,_) -> a) $ filter (\(_,_,a,_) -> a == y) testDatabase
```

---

Incidentally, this code would be more readable if you give the lambdas names:

```
title (t, _, _, _) = t
fans (_, _, _, fs) = fs
year (_, _, y, _) = y
```

And it's more idiomatic to use function chaining:

```
filmsByFan f = map title $ filter (elem f . fans) testDatabase
filmsByYear y = map title $ filter ((== y) . year) testDatabase
```

By now you might be spotting a pattern, which itself can be nicely captured in a higher-order function:

```
filmsBy func = map title $ filter func testDatabase
filmsByFan f = filmsBy (elem f . fans)
filmsByYear y = filmsBy ((== y) . year)
```

Comment: I have amended the code but this is the error I am getting --------------------  No instance for (Eq ([Year] -> Bool))
      arising from a use of `=='
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq ([Year] -> Bool))
    In the expression: elem a == y
    In the first argument of `filter', namely
      `(\ (_, _, a, _) -> elem a == y)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `filter (\ (_, _, a, _) -> elem a == y) testDatabase'

Comment: I've tested it and I'm quite sure it works. How are you calling the function?